# Numpy Lognorm function, used in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, normal-distribution

Suppose you have a dataframe A which looks like this:

```
ID  sigma  miu   prob
1    20    0.5   0.875
2    25    0.2   0.800
3    10    0.4   0.668
4    30    0.6   0.994
```

how can i use python to create another column which does this Excel equivalent calculation?

```
LOGNORM.INV(prob, sigma, exp(miu))
```

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please include your data as text, not picture.

Comment: `scipy.stats.lognorm` returns a `scipy.stats._distn_infrastructure.rv_frozen` object, which is why you get that object in every row,  what exactly are you trying to calculate? maybe the evaluation of the probability density function?

Comment: @jcaliz thanks, i was trying to calculate the inverse of the lognormal, i have edited the question

Answer (score 2):

This is the expected output of the scipy.stats.lognorm function, as stated in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.lognorm.html).

Answer (score 2):

As the error suggests [`scipy.stats.lognorm`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.lognorm.html) does not return an object over which you can iterate. It returns a continuous random variable. It inherits from `scipy`'s generic class `scipy.stats.rv_continuous`, meant for subcalssing.

I'd suggest you to check the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.lognorm.html) so you know what to expect from it and see the methohds it has.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ppf` method to get the of x at which the probability is the desired one

```
data = [20, 25, 10, 30]
miu = [0.5, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6]
prob = [0.875, 0.800, 0.668, 0.994]

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(sigma=data, miu=miu, prob=prob))

df['calc'] = scipy.stats.lognorm(s=df['sigma'], scale=np.exp(df['miu'])).ppf(df.prob)
```